# How do you remove pre-installed apps on a rooted phone?

Tags: nexus-one, root-access, bloatware

I have a rooted Nexus One and want to remove some of the pre-installed applications, like Amazon MP3, for example.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, it annoyed me that there was no way to remove the amazon mp3 app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove pre-installed apps like Peep and Friend Stream from my HTC phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-remove-pre-installed-apps-like-peep-and-friend-stream-from-my-htc-phone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check out the "Barebones" page in CyanogenMod's wiki.](http://web.archive.org/web/20130506101043/http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Barebones)