# How can I remove system apps / stock apps?

Tags: uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)
>   [How to remove pre-installed apps like Peep and Friend Stream from my HTC phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-remove-pre-installed-apps-like-peep-and-friend-stream-from-my-htc-phone?rq=1)

There are alot of stock android apps on my phone like Email, News and Weather etc. that I dont use. I really need the space because my phone is running low on memory so I am wondering if there is a way to uninstall them because I dont see that option in the **Manage apps** section.

Comment: Question: Are you rooted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these can only be removed if you root your device. And even then, some of them you would not want to remove as they tie in to the system.

Additionally, removing them will not free usable space for "non-system" apps. The /system is separate from where user apps are installed and the space is separate.