# Delete pre installed apps under oem/apps folder?

Tags: root-access, system-apps

I have already rooted my android tablet. I am able to access internal system locations e.g. data/data/com.example.src.

However, I am unable to delete aps's under oem/apps folder. I have already tried "RootAppDelete" app to uninstall thses apps, but this app says it has no root access. But the data/data/packagename location only becomes accessable after rooting the device, and as I mentioned above I am able to access this location.

Can someone tell me how to delete apk's under oem/apps folder?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you checked our [bloatware tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info), and tried some of the hints from there? Examples: [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6851/16575) / [How do you remove pre-installed apps on a rooted phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35/16575)

Answer (score 1):

give the root permissions to the RootAppDelete app from the superuser app.

and I would recommend you to use titanium backup to delete pre installed app

Answer (score 0):

it's not that easy to remove those apps. I would suggest installing a custom ROM like Cyanogenmod (that's what I did myself). You might have some problems with apps that do not work under that custom ROM and there is no way back...

I assume that you want to use google play store therefore the "google apps" come by default included in this proprietary package.

I have found a script for doing what you want to do, it didn't work for myself and I ended up using a custom ROM try http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2307355 it is a script which you can modify, you need a rooted device and cwm or twrp

Comment: Without the link, there is no useful information here. If the URL stops working, this answer has no value at all. Please [edit] your answer to include useful information that doesn't require one to follow the link. By all means keep the link to source the original material and for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this : Click file or folder > right click>change permission
After has change then delete file that you want it

Answer (score -1):

If you've Superuser, make sure it is giving the app superuser privileges. I used this app: System App Remover Pro v3.0.1035 (com.jumobile.manager.systemapp.pro)

Comment: I've removed some information from your answer. Note: 1)Permissions can be noticed during installation so no need to mention them here. 2) Size is not relevant since user can come to know it from product's page on Play Store.