# How to delete bloatware from Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 without a PC

Tags: samsung, bloatware

How can I permanently delete Samsung Bloatware from my Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 without connecting to a PC?(I don't have a PC, only a Mac)

I understand that there is a way, but none that show it will work on the Tab Pro.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to root your phone to uninstall bloatware. Search for heimdall; it's the Odin equivalent for Mac. You need to flash a custom recovery first, then root your phone. I don't know / have the specific files you'll need. See if you can find something on Google.

Comment: I've just added the `bloatware` tag to your question. [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info) holds the required information, and links to related questions (e.g. [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6851/16575) / [How do you remove pre-installed apps on a rooted phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35/16575)), please check there.